# Chromecast UK will not connect with Windows 7 laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, chromecast

I am trying to get Chromecast working on an Infinity BT Hub 3 in the UK using my Windows 7 laptop:

- After switching the BT Hub 3 wireless to `Channel 11`, I used the Chromecast app in my Android phone to set up the Chromecast device, and it appears as "Ready to cast". I can see the wallscreen images on my monitor, so it seems the Chromecast device is ready to go.
- I have a Windows 7 laptop connected to the same WiFi. I downloaded the most recent version of the Chromecast setup app from http://chromecast.com/setup
- I have attempted to follow the Chromecast setup on my Windows 7 laptop but it is not working. See snapshot.

[image]

- If I go to my Chrome browser and click on the Chromecast extension button on the top right corner, it tells me: `The selected device is no longer available`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Need more info. What device are you attempting to connect to the Chromecast with? Is that device on the same LAN (e.g. wireless network) as the chromecast, or is it connecting from the outside (the public internet)?

Comment: @allquixotic the device that I plug the Chromecast to is a "dumb" monitor. I then try to set up the Chromecast via the wireless at home, which is a BT HomeHub 3 router.

Comment: I can't believe nobody has found a solution for this. Someone else in the UK must have the same problem...

Comment: Try also the advice in [this article](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/chromecast/bbggk8vDjYw#!topic/chromecast/bbggk8vDjYw). Disconnect every device possible from the network before starting. Have you tried to turn off Smart Setup or 5ghz or putting the router on channel 11?

Comment: It seems changing to `Channel 11` was necessary, but what really made the trick was to use my Android phone to set it up first time around. Now the problem is that my Windows 7 laptop will not connect to it.

Comment: Try maybe using static IP addresses. See also the advice about DNS at the end of [this article](http://www.patronized.ca/technology/install-country-restricted-chromecast-apps/).

Comment: Is the Windows Firewall disabled in Windows 7?  Also what 'type' of network does your PC say you are connected to?  Try switching it to a 'work' network to enable discovery protocols and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @MikeNaylor any ideas where to switch things off with regards to firewall settings? Also, how to switch to 'work' network?

Comment: [Turn off the Windows 7 Firewall](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/522-windows-firewall-turn-off.html) and [change network type](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/43629-network-location-set-home-work-public-network.html)

Comment: @MikeNaylor I cannot really turn off the Firewall in this laptop, since it's also my work laptop and I don't have admin access to turn the firewall off. I tried changing the network type to "work", and still no luck connecting. I also tried setting my Chromecast in a different wireless network to the one at home, and I was successful with my phone, but unsuccessful with my laptop.

Comment: I would try this on another laptop with the firewall disabled.  There are many instances that the Windows Firewall causes issues such as this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromecasts are apparently discovered by the [DIAL](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org) protocol, which builds on UPnP, which often does discovery by sending out UDP **multicasts** with HTTP-like syntax inside.

Doing multicast on Wi-Fi networks is tricky, and vendors get it wrong all the time. Here are some of the top ways it can go wrong, with suggestions for how to test or fix each:

1. Multicast rate is set to high. Some Wi-Fi APs (Access Points; "wireless router" in layman's terms) let you set the multicast rate (sometimes on an "advanced wireless options" screen). For the sake of troubleshooting this, if you can set it, please set it as low as you can. None that if you have, say, a 2.4GHz B/G/N AP, but you have it in N-only mode, you probably can't set the multicast rate as low as it can go unless you re-enable the B/G rates. So make sure it's in B/G/N mode, and set the multicast rate down to 1Mbps if it'll let you.
2. Group cipher and group key problems with WPA2 and WPA. Multicasts have to be encrypted with a different key, and sometimes with a completely different cipher (encryption algorithm) depending on how you have WPA2 or WPA set. For now, just temporarily while troubleshooting, disable all wireless security on your network, to eliminate this possibility.
3. "Wireless client isolation", or "AP isolation", like your Chromecast app suggested. Some APs have a feature that tries to keep wireless devices from being able to talk to each other directly. Disable that.
4. Broken bridging between interfaces on the AP. Some APs don't do a great job of bridging from LAN to WLAN, or from 2.4GHz WLAN to 5GHz WLAN, etc.  If your BT Hub 3 is a simultaneous dual-band AP, make sure to have your laptop join in the same band (2.4 vs. 5GHz) as your Chromecast is joining. Relaying packets between wireless clients is often done in the Wi-Fi radio chipset itself (or its driver), without going through the AP's host OS's bridging code. So if it's your AP's bridging code that's broken, this will hopefully get around it.
5. Broken IGMP Snooping. Since multicasts are a pain on wireless networks, you want to keep any unneeded multicasts off of the wireless. To help do that, some APs do "IGMP Snooping" which lets them see when a client tries to subscribe to, say, a multicast video stream. If the AP sees a client subscribe to a stream via the IGMP protocol, the AP will start forwarding that stream to wireless. But if it doesn't ever see a client ask for a given multicast stream, the AP won't send it to wireless. However, the kind of multicasts that discovery protocols like DIAL/UPnP and Bonjour (mDNS/DNS-SD) use, are NOT the kind that IGMP is supposed to apply to, so a well-written IGMP Snooping implementation will always allow those packets to get through on wireless, because you can't really expect to see anyone issue IGMP requests for them. But if your BT Hub 3 has a broken IGMP Snooping implementation, it might be screwing up. You could go looking for a checkbox (er, "tickbox" in BrE) to turn IGMP Snooping on and off, and whichever way it's set, toggle it so it's set the other way. Maybe it's less broken when it's on than when it's off. Or vice-versa.
6. 802.11 power save mode multicast queueing and delivery. When any wireless clients use 802.11 power save mode (which they all do nowadays), they turn off their Wi-Fi radios for short periods of time to save power. The AP has to do special work to make sure that multicast packets are queued up and delivered at times when all of the clients that care about multicasts have their Wi-Fi receivers turned on to receive them. I have no idea if Chromecast uses 802.11 power save mode (it probably does) or if it gives you a way to disable it (it probably doesn't). If this were a Windows laptop, you can usually go into the advanced driver properties window for your Wi-Fi card and disable power save mode. You can't disable power save mode on the AP, because it's mandatory for APs to support it.
7. Personal firewall software on the client devices. If any of the communication from the Chromecast back to your Win7 laptop is done via multicast to a certain UDP port, and that port is filtered by your personal firewall software, it won't get through to your Chromecast setup app.

I recommend that you try all of the above suggestions all at once, and see if it makes a difference. If not, put everything back and complain to BT and Google. But if it *does* make a difference, then start doing a process-of-elimination to see which change or set of changes made the difference.

Comment: I tried disabling wireless security, which is the only item in the list I can modify even with the "Advanced Settings" for the BTHub3: no difference, still unable to connect the Chromecast.